# Возвращаемый тип для анонимного метода

Tags: c#

Есть анонимный метод (выполняет через рефлексию методы объекта)

```c#
public static T Foo<T>() where T: class
{}
```

Если этот метод в некоторых случаях не должен возвращать ничего, то что тогда передавать в качестве T? void и null, конечно, не подходят

Comment: `Если этот метод в некоторых случаях не должен возвращать ничего` - то эта логика явно не для этого метода.

Comment: То есть в анонимный  метод невозможно передать null?

Comment: Передать-то вы можете все, что угодно, но в C# принято все разбивать на строгие ответственности и делать классы и методы понятными как по названиям, так и по возвращаемым данным. Если у вас метод будет, например `GetPerson`, то он не может отдать человеку допустим, объект "машина", как и не может сделать что-то в фоне и не вернуть результат. Если метод не может обработать логику, то он должен выдать ошибку, которую дальше обработает использующий этот метод человек, либо `..OrDefault`, где на выходе ожидается либо результат, либо `default` значение.

Comment: Ничего не понял. Можно конкретный пример?

Comment: я согласен, наверняка, здесь анонимный метод не очень подходит. Хорошо, конкретнее: задача в том, чтобы совместить в одном методе вызов нескольких однотипных методов. Не хочется плодить множество методов, которые будут содержать в себе 1 строку. Что-то вроде "service.GetSomething". Поэтому решил это собрать в один метод и использовать  рефлексию. Соответственно,  некоторые методы возвращают null. В этом и проблема

Comment: Сейчас это, скорее, заглушка. Поэтому хотелось бы, всё же, узнать, как возможно  передать null-значение

Comment: Ну делайте тогда `return default;`, а метод пусть будет `FooOrDefault<T>()`, тогда вы хотяб в будущем будете знать, что метод может вернуть вам `null`, а не просто что-то выполнит в фоне и все.

Comment: если они возвращают null, это означает что они возвращают что-то, это не void методы, т.е. например они возвращают ссылку на тип User, просто эта ссылка пустая, а вы все равно можете указать `Foo<User>` и тем самым пробрасывать null

Comment: @Exploding Kitten, то, что надо, спасибо! =)

Comment: Это у вас не анонимный метод, а обобщённый (generic).